# Remove ONLY the childrens with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I want to delete ONLY the childrens of an item selected in a datagridview with LINQ to SQL and it doesn't work. I don't know if it's possible to do this. I don't know how to proceed, can you please check at my code and tell me what I do wrong?
Here's my code :

```
private void cmdSupprimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var catAct = (from catA in tbCategories.Categories
                               where catA.CategorieID == (int)dgCategories.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value       
                               select catA).Single();

        for (int i = 0; i < catAct.Jeuxes.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < catAct.Jeuxes[i].Personnages.Count(); j++)
            {
                tbPersos.Personnages.DeleteOnSubmit(catAct.Jeuxes[i].Personnages[j]);
            }
            tbJeux.Jeuxes.DeleteOnSubmit(catAct.Jeuxes[i]);
        }
        tbCategories.Categories.DeleteOnSubmit(catAct);

        tbCategories.SubmitChanges();

        dgCategories.DataSource = null;
        dgCategories.DataSource = (from cats in tbCategories.Categories
                                   select new CategorieDisplay()
                                   {
                                       CategoryID = cats.CategorieID,
                                       CategoryNom = cats.CategorieNom
                                   }).ToList();

        MessageBox.Show("Les enfants de cette catégorie ont été supprimés");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: the beginning of my code is in the description in the top of the page

Comment: "it doesn't work", so what *does* is do?

Comment: I have an error about an invalid cast at the line : where catA.CategorieID == (int)dgCategories.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value

Comment: OMG, so *tell* that right away. You can't just cast anything to `int`.

Comment: So how can I proceed to get the number of the selected Category?

Answer (score 0):

Make your datasource a variable called data.  Then you can delete rows from the data and the datagridview will also get updated.

```
var data = (from cats in tbCategories.Categories
                                   select new CategorieDisplay()
                                   {
                                       CategoryID = cats.CategorieID,
                                       CategoryNom = cats.CategorieNom
                                   }).ToList();

dgCategories.DataSource = data;
​
```

Comment: I have to place this code before my MessageBox.Show or after the beginning of my Try?

Comment: Replace the current code.  The row number in the DataGridView and the data array are the same.  So if you want to remove row 4 of the DGV then remove row 4 from data.